# jquery/css transition when reached top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I detect via my jQuery when you are at the top of the page. When you reach the top of the page I show a larger logo. When you're not at the top of the screen the logo is a bit smaller. It works great but I want to make it smooth with a little transition. But it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 1) {
            jQuery('.navbar-brand>div').addClass('small-logo');
        } else {
            jQuery('.navbar-brand>div').removeClass('small-logo');
        }
});
```

And here are my css classes:

```
.logo{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 1s;
    transition: height 1s;
}

.small-logo{
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 1s;
    transition: height 1s;
}
```

Anyone can help my out with this little animation?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try making a jsfiddle so we can... fiddle =P

Comment: @CalebO'Leary I'll do my best to recreate my issue, one moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `transition` multiple times in a rules just overwrites the previous ones (*moreover if you remove a property in one of the two classes it will not be animated, you have to state the new value so you should include the `top-margin` in the second rule with `0` value*)

```
.logo{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}

.small-logo{
    margin-top:0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

---

It would be even cleaner though to keep the initial class and just toggle a new one for the change (*with only the properties that change between the two states*)

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    jQuery('.navbar-brand > .logo').toggleClass('small', jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 1);
});
```

and

```
.logo{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 125px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}

.logo.small{
    margin-top:0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I've tried your answer and doesn't change much, unfortunately.

Comment: My bad I'm just stupid! Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this numerous times using skrollr.js.  It's a lot easier and more powerful then what you're trying to do here.  You can build in a ton of scrolling animations easily.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr